# Which version of JRE should I bundle when converting .jar to exe using launch4j

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jvm, launch4j

I want to convert the .jar to .exe using launch4j.
Which version of JRE should I bundle?
32-bit JRE or 64-bit JRE?
I am using 64-bit eclipse to develop javafx application.

And also, I have faced the error of “fail to create virtual machine” when running .exe file after converting.

Comment: I would assume you'd want to bundle the exact same version you're developing with. Side note: If you're using Java 14+ then it may be easier to use `jpackage`.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit programs can run on a 64-bit system, but 64-bit programs will not run on a 32-bit system. This is because 64-bit applications include 64-bit instructions that will not be recognized by a 32-bit processor.

But I would recommend to go for the version which you expect your target system(probable users of the application) would use.

Nowadays most systems are 64 Bit systems thus it doesn't matter much.
But if you know that your application will be used on old systems or 32 bit systems then go for 32 bit version.

And for the version (like 8 or 9 or 14) you should always go with the version of Java with which you have done the development!

That is very important as old Java versions will not run the program if it has been compiled by a newer JDK.

So use the Java version you used during development.